# Was Summon Succubus errataed at some point?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e, errata

The Summon Succubus spell for Wizard, printed in Dragon 385, seems to have some issues that my group is trying to figure out. Specifically, we've found two versions of the Intrinsic Nature, and they are wildly different.

From the Dragon 385 PDF

> Intrinsic Nature: If you haven’t given the succubus any commands by
> the end of your turn, it shifts 1 square and attacks you or your
> nearest ally within range.

and from the compendium (both offline and portable)

> Intrinsic Nature: If you haven't given the succubus any commands by
> the end of your turn, it shifts 1 square and attacks the nearest enemy
> within range that is not dominated. In addition, you are dazed until
> the end of your next turn.

During the discussion, we've found some supporting secondary information for both, but the change is not present in either the compiled 4e errata or in the errata for Dragon 385.

In favor of the PDF is, well, the initial printing, as well as the individual article for Class Acts: Wizard. There's also this power description in an old Wizard handbook on of our members dug up from 2010

> Summon Succubus (D 385) Charm, Summoning: for lash-lovers this summon adds incredible control, in the form of constant field superiority. Each target can be dominated only once, but this is often enough. A great form of control, and the intrisic nature isn't too shabby, even if it raises a question: if the succubus attacks an ally and dominates it, i am her controller, so the round isn't completely wasted.

Which is odd since I would never describe that intrinsic as anything other than raw downside, but does acknowledge it dominating allies, which the compendium version cannot do.

Meanwhile, in favor of the compendium version is the character builder (though notably that is not a rules source) and the later Wizard handbook from 2012

> Summon Succubus. (D385) Charm, Summoning. She dominates with her attacks. She can even do outside your turn if you're willing to take being dazed (Hint, Superior Will). Her Symbiosis effect is nice, but nothing special, although it does help to counter the CA you grant from being dazed. A fantastic power.

This references both the general amazingness of a minor>no action dominate, as well as working to mitigate the daze drawback only present in the compendium version.

However, as mentioned, we can't find any evidence of official errata or reprinting. Does anyone know where this change was made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find an old /tg/ thread from March 10th, 2010 (the date the article was released), that had the original text copy and pasted into it. It matches the compendium.

> Intrinsic Nature: If you haven’t given the succubus any commands by the end of your turn, it shifts 1 square and attacks the nearest enemy within range that is not dominated. In addition, you are dazed until the end of your next turn.

https://warosu.org/tg/thread/8502743

By March 30th, 2010, the copy of the PDF of this article I have on my hard drive has changed to the new text in the PDF. Looks like it never made it back into the compendium.

> Intrinsic Nature: If you haven’t given the succubus any commands by the end of your turn, it shifts 1 square and attacks you or your nearest ally within range.

As such, it seems the above text is the correct text.

Comment: Yeah, I did some digging with other members of my group, and the best we could track down was a Penny Arcade PbP game from 2010 where it got banned, someone commented on the "at-will minor action dominate", and then on the next page the DM unbanned it saying it had been nerfed, which seems to line up with what you found.